# Why am I getting a 401 error with Yelp API?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, fetch-api, yelp

I created this app with EJS, Express, Nodejs, and the Yelp API, and I wanted to do it over again using React as the frontend this time since I started learning React. The way the app works is that once the form is submitted, it would load a new page with all the information about a random restaurant. It worked perfectly with EJS, but I'm having trouble getting it to work with React. I used the GET method on the form, but I'm not sure how to use it with React. I keep getting a 401 error every time I submit the form. I didn't really change anything in the backend, so it's basically the same code. I checked it with nodemon, and it does work. I also console logged the api key to see if I get it, and I do get it. I tried different things, and I still can't figure out my problem. If anyone can help, I would really appreciate it!

index.ejs from previous app

```
<section class="whole">
    <form id="myForm" action="/selection" method="GET">
    <h3>Location</h3>
        <input id="city" type="text" name="cityInput" placeholder="Zip or City & State" required>
    //the rest of the input form code
    <br>
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

REACT:

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Logo from './images/rest6.png'
import "./style.css";

function App() {

    const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState(
        {
        city: "",
        price: "",
        category: ""
        }
    )


    function handleChange(event) {
        const {name, value, type, checked} = event.target
        setFormData(prevChoice => {
            return {
                ...prevChoice,
                [name]: value
            }
        })
    }


    function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log(formData)
        
        fetch(`/selection`)
        .then((response) => console.log(response));
    }

    return (
        
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <h3>Location</h3>
            <input type="text" name="city" onChange={handleChange} value={formData.city || ""} placeholder="Zip or City & State" />

            <h3 className="priceHeader">Price</h3>

            <section id="priceSection">
            <label className="radioLabel" htmlFor="priceOne">
                <input onChange={handleChange} id="priceOne" type="radio" value="1" name="price" checked={formData.price === "1"} required oninvalid="alert('You must fill out the form!');" />
                <div className="radioButtons">
                    <i className="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-dollar-sign"></i>
                </div>
            </label>

            <label className="radioLabel" htmlFor="priceTwo">
                <input onChange={handleChange} id="priceTwo" type="radio" value="2" name="price" checked={formData.price === "2"} />
                <div className="radioButtons">
                    <i className="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-dollar-sign"></i>
                    <i className="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-dollar-sign"></i>
                </div>
            </label>

            <label className="radioLabel" htmlFor="priceThree">
                <input onChange={handleChange} id="priceThree" type="radio" value="3" name="price" checked={formData.price === "3"} />
                <div className="radioButtons">
                    <i className="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-dollar-sign"></i>
                    <i className="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-dollar-sign"></i>
                    <i className="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-dollar-sign"></i>
                </div>
            </label>

            <label className="radioLabel" htmlFor="priceFour">
                <input onChange={handleChange} id="priceFour" type="radio" value="4" name="price" checked={formData.price === "4"} />
                <div className="radioButtons">
                    <i className="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-dollar-sign"></i>
                    <i className="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-dollar-sign"></i>
                    <i className="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-dollar-sign"></i>
                    <i className="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-dollar-sign"></i>
                </div>
            </label>
            
            <label className="radioLabel" htmlFor="priceAll">
                <input onChange={handleChange} id="priceAll" type="radio" value="1,2,3,4" name="price" checked={formData.price === "1,2,3,4"} />
                <div className="radioButtons">
                <p className="radioInputAll">All</p>
                </div>
            </label>
            </section>

            <h3 className="categoryHeader">Categories</h3>
            <section className="foodType">
            <label className="radioLabel">
                <input onChange={handleChange} type="radio" value="mexican" name="category" checked={formData.category === "mexican"} required oninvalid="alert('You must fill out the form!');" />
                <div className="radioButtons categoryButtons">
                    <p className="radioInputText">Mexican</p>
                    </div>
            </label>
            <label className="radioLabel" htmlFor="mediterranean">
                <input onChange={handleChange} type="radio" id="mediterranean" value="mediterranean" name="category" checked={formData.category === "mediterranean"} />
                <div className="radioButtons categoryButtons">
                    <p className="radioInputText">Mediterranean</p>
                    </div>
            </label>

            <label className="radioLabel" htmlFor="sushi">
                <input onChange={handleChange} type="radio" id="sushi" value="sushi" name="category" checked={formData.category === "sushi"} />
                <div className="radioButtons categoryButtons">
                    <p className="radioInputText">Sushi</p>
                    </div>
            </label>

            <label className="radioLabel">
                <input onChange={handleChange} type="radio" value="pizza" name="category" checked={formData.category === "pizza"} />
                <div className="radioButtons categoryButtons">
                    <p className="radioInputText">Pizza</p>
                    </div>
            </label>

            <label className="radioLabel">
                <input onChange={handleChange} type="radio" value="korean" name="category" checked={formData.category === "korean"} />
                <div className="radioButtons categoryButtons">
                    <p className="radioInputText">Korean</p>
                    </div>
            </label>

            <label className="radioLabel">
                <input onChange={handleChange} type="radio" value="coffee" name="category" checked={formData.category === "coffee"} />
                <div className="radioButtons categoryButtons">
                    <p className="radioInputText">Coffee</p>
                    </div>
            </label>

            <label className="radioLabel">
                <input onChange={handleChange} type="radio" value="burgers" name="category" checked={formData.category === "burgers"} />
                <div className="radioButtons categoryButtons">
                    <p className="radioInputText">Burger</p>
                    </div>
            </label>

            <label className="radioLabel">
                <input onChange={handleChange} type="radio" value="food" name="category" checked={formData.category === "food"} />
                <div className="radioButtons categoryButtons">
                    <p className="radioInputText">None</p>
                    </div>
            </label>
            </section>

        <br />
        <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
    )
}
export default App;
```

index.js

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const yelp = require('yelp-fusion');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.set(express.static('public'));


const api_key = process.env.API_KEY


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));


//route for index page
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.render("index");
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
console.log("Running on " + port)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
});

let restaurant,
    city, 
    price,
    category,
    num = 0;



app.get('/selection', (req, res) => {
    console.log('running')
    city = req.query.city;
    price = req.query.price;
    category = req.query.category;
    
    console.log(Object.keys(req.query) )
    console.log(Object.keys(req.params) )
    console.log(Object.keys(req) )
  
    console.log("category: " + category)
    console.log("city: " + city)
    console.log("price: " + price)
    console.log("RES: " + res.locals.user);

    const url = `https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?location=${city}&categories=${category}&price=${price}&sort_by=best_match&limit=50`

    console.log(url)
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        accept: 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${api_key}`
      }
    };
          
    fetch(url, options)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        console.log("result: ", response);
        num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Object.keys(response.businesses).length));
        console.log(response.businesses[num])
        console.log("Number of Choices: " + (Object.keys(response.businesses).length))
        console.log("random number: " + num)
        restaurant = response.businesses[num]
        res.render('rest', {
          restaurant: restaurant
        })
        res.status(200).send(response);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(401).send(err);
        console.error(err)
      });
});
```

Comment: You should definitely not use `res.render()` and `res.send()` together. It unlikely you want to render an EJS template for an API response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```js
> fetch(`/selection`)
> ```

You aren't adding anything in to the query string here so `req.query` will be empty on the server-side.

You can easily encode your `formData` state using [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

```js
fetch(`/selection?${new URLSearchParams(formData)}`)
```

This will produce a URL like `/selection?city=Liverpool&price=1&category=pizza` (depending on the actual values in your `formData` state).

---

[401](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) is an odd choice to set for literally any error that might occur server-side.

Instead, I would log all the appropriate details of the error and respond with a generic downstream API error message with [502](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/502) status.

```js
fetch(url, options)
  .then((response) => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      const err = new Error("Downstream API request failed");
      err.status = response.status;
      err.response = response;
      throw err;
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((response) => {
    // ... as above but you don't want res.render()
  })
  .catch(async (err) => {
    console.error(err.status, await err.response?.text(), err);
    res.status(502).send(err);
  });
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! I'm still a bit confused on the fetch section. Is "fetch(`/selection?${new URLSearchParams(formData)}`)" the format that it tends to be for a GET request in React? I still have a lot to learn. I would appreciate any readings or articles to learn more about this. I mostly found information on POST requests for React.

Comment: @liverpool09 it's just a request with a query string, eg `GET /selection?city=Liverpool&price=1&category=pizza`. It's nothing specifically to do with React.